# Why does iostream require the exception handler to be called while using vcvarsall.bat to compile 'Hello World'?

Tags: c++, exception, compiler-errors

Attempting to compile the following code with vcvarsall.bat in command line throws a warning saying that the exception handler is needed in the code but not called before using `/EHsc`.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The batch file:

```
@echo off

cl C:\Development\..\basicmath.cpp
```

The warning:

```
C:\...\ostream(746): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
C:...\basicmath.cpp(10): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator <<<std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,const char *)' being compiled
```

Line 743 - 754 of ostream line 746 (from error) is _TRY:

```
if (!_Ok) {
        _State |= ios_base::badbit;
    } else { // state okay, insert
        _TRY_IO_BEGIN
        if ((_Ostr.flags() & ios_base::adjustfield) != ios_base::left) {
            for (; 0 < _Pad; --_Pad) { // pad on left
                if (_Traits::eq_int_type(_Traits::eof(), _Ostr.rdbuf()->sputc(_Ostr.fill()))) {
                    _State |= ios_base::badbit; // insertion failed, quit
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Adding /EHsc to my batch file will allow it to run but I would like to know why this is.  **Why does this block of code from the file for output require EHsc to be called?**

MSDOCS says EHsc is for cleanup to prevent memory leaks, what is causing the leak and why do they need an external program to fix the leak instead of fixing it in the same file (this may sound rude but its just ignorant)?

*Edit: thank you for pointing out its a warning and not an error.*

Comment: Note: this is not an error, it's a warning. It doesn't prevent compilation from succeeding unless you have `/WX` option on (treat warnings as errors). I must say, it seems to be a strange decision from the developers of the compiler if they first define behaviour A as default and then recommend to change it to behaviour B, which is better. I guess there must be a reason for that. A TL;DR answer is really that- add `/EHs` (or `/EHsc`) to your compilation options in all projects and you can forget about the topic.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out it's a warning and not an error, I didn't even pay attention to the fact that it still created my `.exe` just fine and it runs without problem.  I get super focused if anything but success is shown.

Comment: By default `cl` does not compile for standard C++. It compiles for a microsoft-specific dialect that supports (among other things) SEH (a Microsoft-specific means of Structured Exception Handling) and stack unwinding (what happens when exceptions propagate up the call stack). Some functions in `<iostream>` throw C++ exceptions.   The `s` in `/EHsc` enables stack unwinding consistent with what the C++ standard requires. The `c` directs the compiler to assume `extern "C"` functions do not throw. When IDEs use `cl` behind the scenes to compile C++, they usually enable those options by default.

Comment: Interesting, if I understand, which I might not, cl is part of vcvarsall.bat specifically so if I use a different compiler it won’t use cl and will have eh by default?

Comment: @peter Or it won’t NEED eh by default because SEH won’t be present?

Comment: @BornGeek - As I understand it, SEH is supported by default - if your code uses SEH only without C++ exceptions, it will work.   It is stack-unwinding consistent with requirements of standard C++ that needs to be enabled (assuming you have code that can potentially throw C++ exceptions - which is the case with `<iostream>` - iostreams don't throw exceptions by default, but changing that is possible at run time).

Comment: @Peter thank you for the info, have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer:

Add `/EHs` or `/EHsc` to your compilation options as [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=msvc-160) suggests. It's the most portable option regarding exceptions handling, if you will ever need to execute the same code on Unix machine.

---

#### Long answer:

There are two parts to this question. First is why the warning occurs in `iostream` and the second is what does the warning mean.

**Why are there exceptions in `iostream`?**

The default behaviour of streams in C++ is exceptionless - any failure is represented by setting an internal fail bit, accessible with `eof()`, `fail()` and `bad()` functions. However, you can change this behaviour to throwing exceptions on failure by using [`exceptions()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) method on stream. You can choose which fail bits trigger exceptions, but the main point is that the code must be there by standard. The warning seems to analyze only that - it notices a possible path where `throw` occurs and reports a warning.

**What does the warning mean?**

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=msvc-160) (emphasis mine):

> By default (that is, if no `/EHsc`, `/EHs`, or `/EHa` option is specified), the compiler supports SEH handlers in the native C++ `catch(...)` clause. **However, it also generates code that only partially supports C++ exceptions** . The default exception unwinding code doesn't destroy automatic C++ objects outside of try blocks that go out of scope because of an exception.

The issue is that (for some reason) MSVC compiler by default generates assembly which is wrong according to the standard. Stack unwinding will not be perfomerd when exception is thrown, which may cause memory leaks and other unexpected behaviours.

An example correct C++ code, which has a memory leak under the default setting:

```
void foo()
{
    std::string str = "This is a very long string. It definitely doesn't use Small String Optimization and it must be allocated on the heap."
    std::cout << str;
    throw std::runtime_error{"Oh no, something went wrong"};
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        foo();
    }
    catch (std::exception&)
    {
        // str in foo() was possibly not released, because it wasn't deleted when exception was thrown!
    }
}
```

So the final answer would be:

- If you plan to use [Structured Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=msvc-160) (like divide-by-zero or invalid memory access errors) or use a library that uses them, use `/EHa`
- If you don't need to catch SEs, choose `/EHs` for compatibility with C++ standard and portability
- Never leave the defaults, always set `/EH` to one alternative or another, otherwise you will have to deal with strange behaviours when using exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Another user @peter mentioned “By default cl does not compile for standard C++. It compiles for a microsoft-specific dialect that supports (among other things) SEH (a Microsoft-specific means of Structured Exception Handling) and stack unwinding (what happens when exceptions propagate up the call stack).”  Are there any other compilers that would not have this issue?

Comment: While iostreams don't throw exceptions by default, that can be changed at run time.  So the compiler is sort-of obligated to check if there is any execution path that will potentially throw  exceptions.   Since `<iostream>` classes are templated, the compiler typically has visibility of those potential execution paths, but doesn't have visibility of whether other code (in other compilation units) also uses C++ streams, and enables exception handling on some streams.

Answer (score 1):

That's a warning so your current program compiles fine. But problems come up in programs as such:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    A(int x):x(x) {
        std::cout<<"Contructed A::"<<x<<'\n';
    }
    ~A() {
        std::cout<<"Destructed A::"<<x<<'\n';
    }
private:
    int x;
};


void foo() {
    A a{2};
    throw std::bad_exception{};
}

int main()
{
    A a {1};
    try {
        foo();
    } catch(const std::bad_exception& ex) {
        std::cout<<ex.what()<<'\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Using `cl test.cpp` yields the output:

```
Contructed A::1
Contructed A::2
bad exception
Destructed A::1
```

While using `cl test.cpp /EHsc` yields:

```
Contructed A::1
Contructed A::2
Destructed A::2
bad exception
Destructed A::1
```

This behavior is explained by the documentation for the warning [C4530](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4530?view=msvc-160):

> When the /EHsc option isn't enabled, automatic storage objects in the
> stack frames between the throwing function and the function where the
> exception is caught don't get destroyed. Only the automatic storage
> objects created in a try or catch block get destroyed, which can lead
> to significant resource leaks and other unexpected behavior.

That explains `a {2}` not being destructed when the program wasn't compiled with `/EHsc`.

And of course,

> If no exceptions can possibly be thrown in your executable, you may
> safely ignore this warning.

So, for a program like

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    std::printf("hello world\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

`cl.exe` quietly compiles.

Comment: Thank you, this is inline with my unexperienced attempts to find other libraries that work without warning. The issue is still there even when using other libraries it just does so quietly?

Comment: @BornGeek Any library that involves exception handling would have the same problem. I think this is just a limitation with the Microsoft compiler. `g++`/`clang` doesn't have this problem.